# How can I restore etcd cluster from snapshot in docker image on CoreOS?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, coreos, etcd

I have a Kubernetes cluster (v1.5.6) with 3 nodes etcd cluster (etcd version 3.1.5) on vmware.
This etcd nodes are running in three docker containers(on three hosts) on coreos on vmware.

I try to backup etcd with the following solution:

```
docker run --rm --net=host -v /tmp:/etcd_backup -e ETCDCTL_API=3 quay.io/coreos/etcd:v3.1.5 etcdctl --endpoints=[1.1.1.1:2379,2.2.2.2:2379,3.3.3.3:2379] snapshot save etcd_backup/snapshot.db
```

The backup has been completed succesfully.

I want to create this kubernetes cluster from zero in another vmware environment, but I need to restore etcd from snapshot for this.

So far, I have not found the right solution that works with etcd in docker containers.

I try to restore with the following method, but unfortunately I did not succeed.

First, I created a new etcd node after I run the following command:

```
docker run --rm --net=host -v /tmp/etcd_bak:/etcd_backup -e ETCDCTL_API=3 registry:5000/quay.io/coreos/etcd:v3.1.5 etcdctl snapshot restore etcd_backup/snapshot.db --name etcd0 --initial-cluster etcd0=http://etcd0:2380,etcd1=http://etcd1:2380,etcd2=http://etcd2:2380 --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://etcd0:2380
```

Result:

```
2018-06-04 09:25:52.314747 I | etcdserver/membership: added member 7ff5c9c6942f82e [http://etcd0:2380] to cluster 5d1b637f4b7740d5
2018-06-04 09:25:52.314940 I | etcdserver/membership: added member 91b417e7701c2eeb [http://etcd2:2380] to cluster 5d1b637f4b7740d5
2018-06-04 09:25:52.315096 I | etcdserver/membership: added member faeb78734ee4a93d [http://etcd1:2380] to cluster 5d1b637f4b7740d5
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens.

What is the good solution to restore the etcd backup?

How do I create an empty etcd cluster/node and how should I restore the snapshot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to the Etcd [Disaster Recovery](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/op-guide/recovery.md) document, you need restore all three etcd nodes from snapshot with commands like yours, then run three node with commands like this:

```
etcd \
  --name m1 \
  --listen-client-urls http://host1:2379 \
  --advertise-client-urls http://host1:2379 \
  --listen-peer-urls http://host1:2380 &
```

Also, you can extract etcdctl from the image, like this:

```
docker run --rm -v /opt/bin:/opt/bin registry:5000/quay.io/coreos/etcd:v3.1.5 cp /usr/local/bin/etcdctl /opt/bin
```

Then use etcdctl to restore snapshot:

```
# ETCDCTL_API=3 ./etcdctl snapshot restore snapshot.db \
  --name m1 \
  --initial-cluster m1=http://host1:2380,m2=http://host2:2380,m3=http://host3:2380 \
  --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 \
  --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://host1:2380 \
  --data-dir /var/lib/etcd
```

This will restore snapshot to the /var/lib/etcd directory. Then start etcd with docker, don't forget mount /var/lib/etcd into your container, and specify --data-dir to it .

Comment: Thanks.

But, my etcd nodes are running in docker containers, not natively on the CoreOS. In this case, if the docker image is not running, I can't restore the snapshot, on the other hand, how can I run the same docker image with another commands?

Unfortunately, this part is unclear to me.

Comment: I managed to restore the cluster based on your instructions, thank you.
Unfortunately, my v3 backup does not contains the v2 keys (only the events). I have old CoreOS version on minions with etcdctl 2.3.7. (And my k8s cluster version is 1.5.6.)I have to try a v2 backup/restore procedures.

Answer (score 3):

Ectd in kubernetes is running in Docker containers, here was what I did to recovery the cluster:

- retrieve Etcd cluster metedata

  ```
  docker inspect etcd1
  ```

  you'd got something like below:

  ```
  "Binds": [
      "/etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs:ro",
      "/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl:/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl:ro",
      "/var/lib/etcd:/var/lib/etcd:rw"
  ],
  ...
  "Env": [
      "ETCD_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/etcd",
      "ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS=https://172.16.60.1:2379",
      "ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS=https://172.16.60.1:2380",
      "ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE=existing",
      "ETCD_METRICS=basic",
      "ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS=https://172.16.60.1:2379,https://127.0.0.1:2379",
      "ETCD_ELECTION_TIMEOUT=5000",
      "ETCD_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL=250",
      "ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TOKEN=k8s_etcd",
      "ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS=https://172.16.60.1:2380",
      "ETCD_NAME=etcd1",
      "ETCD_PROXY=off",
      "ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER=etcd1=https://172.16.60.1:2380,etcd2=https://172.16.60.2:2380,etcd3=https://172.16.60.2:2380",
      "ETCD_AUTO_COMPACTION_RETENTION=8",
      "ETCD_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/ca.pem",
      "ETCD_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-node01.pem",
      "ETCD_KEY_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-node01-key.pem",
      "ETCD_PEER_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/ca.pem",
      "ETCD_PEER_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-node01.pem",
      "ETCD_PEER_KEY_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-node01-key.pem",
      "ETCD_PEER_CLIENT_CERT_AUTH=true",
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
  ],
  "Cmd": [
      "/usr/local/bin/etcd"
  ],
  ```
- copy etcd snapshotdb to other etcd nodes

  ```
  scp snapshotdb_20180913 node02:/root/  
  scp snapshotdb_20180913 node03:/root/
  ```
- rebuild a new cluster with original info

  ```
  # etcd1
  docker stop etcd1
  rm -rf /var/lib/etcd

  ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl snapshot restore snapshotdb_20180913 \
    --cacert /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/ca.pem \
    --cert /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-node01.pem \
    --key /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-node01-key.pem \
    --name etcd1 \
    --initial-cluster etcd1=https://node01:2380,etcd2=https://node02:2380,etcd3=https://node03:2380 \
    --initial-cluster-token k8s_etcd \
    --initial-advertise-peer-urls https://node01:2380 \
    --data-dir /var/lib/etcd

  # etcd2
  docker stop etcd2
  rm -rf /var/lib/etcd

  ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl snapshot restore snapshotdb_20180913 \
    --cacert /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/ca.pem \
    --cert /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-node02.pem \
    --key /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-node02-key.pem \
    --name etcd2 \
    --initial-cluster etcd1=https://node01:2380,etcd2=https://node02:2380,etcd3=https://node03:2380 \
    --initial-cluster-token k8s_etcd \
    --initial-advertise-peer-urls https://node02:2380 \
    --data-dir /var/lib/etcd

  # etcd3
  docker stop etcd3
  rm -rf /var/lib/etcd

  ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl snapshot restore snapshotdb_20180913 \
    --cacert /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/ca.pem \
    --cert /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-node03.pem \
    --key /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-node03-key.pem \
    --name etcd3 \
    --initial-cluster etcd1=https://node01:2380,etcd2=https://node02:2380,etcd3=https://node03:2380 \
    --initial-cluster-token k8s_etcd \
    --initial-advertise-peer-urls https://node03:2380 \
    --data-dir /var/lib/etcd
  ```
- start containers and check cluster status

  ```
  cd /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl
  etcdctl \
    --endpoints=https://node01:2379 \
    --ca-file=./ca.pem \
    --cert-file=./member-node01.pem \
    --key-file=./member-node01-key.pem \
    member list
  ```

Comment: Thanks for posting, content concerning etcd backup and restore is pretty scarce. 
Btw this may be of interest to you: 
https://labs.consol.de/kubernetes/2018/05/25/kubeadm-backup.html
It's about a cronjob to automate etcd backups. 

Heptio Ark is another cool DR thing to check out.